# UICollection header full in iphone x

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm working in a `UICollectionView`and I'm using the "Setion Header" option, everything is working fine except that in landscape mode the iPhone X does not fill completely.

I tried to find a solution for example with this but it does not work for me:

```
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        myCollection?.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always
    }
```

**Any suggestions on this?**

In portraid it looks good:

[image: my collection app]

[image: PORTRAID]

Order of my views:

[image: views]

Comment: How does it look in portrait mode...??

Comment: set myCollection?.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
and set section inset manually

Comment: @Amit In portraid it looks good!!

Comment: @SPatel. with `myCollection?.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never` does not work either

Comment: It looks like this is not related to the section header, because the items within the section are also inset. You might get better answers if you change the question to be about UICollectionView instead of UICollectionViewHeader. To verify this, you can try to set a non-white background color on your collection view.

Comment: @AlbertB, can you post your ViewController

Comment: @AlbertB what about section inset, did you set it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use size classes for it.

In Storyboard click on `view as` at the bottom :

[image]

and change the orientation to landscape.

Select the trailing constraint of `collectionView` :

[image] 
[image]

introduce the variation for the constraint for `compact-compact` as -44.

[image]

The final UI will be :

[image]

Repeat the same process for leading constraint.
Hope it helps what you want to achieve here. Happy coding

**Edit**

Googled and got the same question in SO:

- [UICollectionView in landscape on iPhone X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46258444/uicollectionview-in-landscape-on-iphone-x)

May be this helps what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'm trying but the order of my views: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPjuX.jpg Trailing space: superview no safeArea. My view is inside `collection reusable view`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that Leading and trailing constraints of `collectionView`

Comment: A query, I just see that the content of the UICollection also moved under the notch?

Comment: With its suggestion and adding this code works perfectly (the content of the UICOLLECTION no longer moves, only the header section) `if let flowLayout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        flowLayout.sectionInsetReference = .fromSafeArea
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

Remove Leading trailing constraints and add Leading and trailing constraints **0** from **view** not from **safe area** for your collection view.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, my `View header`  have these constraints ==> Trailing space to: Superview: 0
Leading space to: Superview: 0

Comment: I was talking about collection view constraints.